# Android: How to make all elements inside LinearLayout same size?

Tags: android, layout

I would like to create a dialog to display a video title and tags. Below text I would like to add buttons View, Edit and Delete and make these elements same size. Does anyone know how to modify .xml layout file in order to make elements inside LinearView same size?

The current layout file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/txtTitle" android:text="[Title]" >
          </TextView>

          <TextView 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/txtTags"            
              android:text="[Tags]" >
          </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/btnPlay" 
           android:text="View">
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit" 
            android:text="Edit">
        </Button>

        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete" 
            android:text="Delete">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could show the solution by modifying the pasted file content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use `android:layout_width="0px"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on the three `Button`s. That says the buttons should take up no more than 0 pixels, but the three of them should split any extra space between them. That should give you the visual effect you wish.

Comment: If you _REALLY_ wanted to you could alternatively use a TableLayout with android:stretchColumns="0,1,2".

Comment: Awesome...so this means, if we put width as 0px, weight will override the settings? Why is it so?

Comment: This does not work if your Buttons are in a `GridLayout`. In this case they really become `0px` wide. Maybe `GridLayout` doesn't accept `layout_weight`?

Comment: @Zelphir: `GridLayout` definitely does not use `layout_weight`. That is only used by `LinearLayout`, and perhaps some subclasses of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 35):

Another way is to make `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` this will also works fine!!!

Comment: You were really excited about this answer. :-) Love the enthusiasm!

Comment: CommonsWare's solution didn't work for me, but this did it! :) I used "match_parent" since I heard you should prefer it over "fill_parent", but both work.

Comment: The **LinearLayout** parent of those elements must have also **layout_width="match_parent"**.

Answer (score 22):

Use [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with your desired [weightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) and create elements with equal [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight). Here is an example ...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_36dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_36dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_note_white_36dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_brush_white_36dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_white_36dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, the weight sum of all elements is 5. Here is the screenshot ...

[image]

Note that, [Google Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons) icons are used. Hope this is helpful.