# LinearLayout text wrap problem when having two buttons of same size plus one stretched in the center

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

Looks like there's a plenty of questions about centering, same size etc, but so far I didn't find the exactly my case so I dare to ask :)

What I need is a layout of three buttons like this:

```
[ previous ][*select*] [  next  ]
```

where **[previous]** and **[next]** buttons are of the **same** size (i.e. in this case, size of the **[previous]** button as it is bigger), and the **[*select*]** button should stretch to occupy all of the available width.

Following the hints of making two buttons in LinearLayout same sized, i came up with the following xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Select" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This *almost* works :)
Except one thing: instead of making **Next** button to match the size of **Previous** button, android makes **Previous** button to be the size of the **Next** :)
And because of this the text "Previous" gets wrapped in two lines, like

```
Previ
ous
```

Dunno if this is a bug or not, but can you advice me a workaround or some another way to achive the desired layout?

Thank you!

Comment: ah, and i also tried to specify textview's "android:singleLine=true" attribute for the buttons - it didn't help

Comment: A post having a similar issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size

Comment: yes, i used that post to make my xml. but the thing is that while it somewhat works, i have an issue with a wrapping text (see the ending part of my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:clickable="false">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/previous"

    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous" 

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/next"

    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next" 

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/previous"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should work.

Comment: tried it, but the result is not exactly what i want: Previous and Next buttons are of different widths, while i'd like Next to be the same as Previous :)

Comment: You can set the width of the buttons manually (answer updated) and then they would be the same width. I don't know if that helps, maybe you don't want a fixed width.

Comment: Also, you can try this approach the other way round: set the center button's width and place the other two to its right and left, setting their width to fill_parent. You'll need to change the layout to achieve this, but you'll make sure the two buttons are the same width.

The problem, then, is the width to assign to the center button :)

Comment: Yep, I'm starting to think this is the only way, though not perfect.

instead of specifiyng fixed width, i could go with specifying "minWidth" - should be better :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are including "android:layout_weight" you should give either "android:layout_width" or "android:layout_height" as "fill_parent"

modify your code like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/button_bar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Previous" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:text="Select" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Next" />
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. this way the select button even dissapears from screen because it tries to match the parent's width twice as much as other two are ;)

Comment: I have edited the post.. it was the problem in giving weight.. now it will work fine...
try it out!!

Comment: You can play around with "android:layout_weight"

Comment: oh, now it works better, but somehow it ends up with the same issue I originally had. here, take a look:
http://imagebin.ca/view/IbuT9Pp2.html

Comment: I have edited the post made android:layout_weight="1.5"
i think this is your exact answer !!!

Comment: This solution does seem to work but if you change the length of the string "next" or "previous", it can become quite ugly...

Comment: Your solution did work for me as long as I have the same weight for previous and Next actually

Comment: @Sephy "layout_weight" takes a float value and you can find out solution for you layout using trail and error method

Comment: @Eby, yes, it works, but if you make the "previous" string longer (e.g. "Previous blalblalal" it will break again. 

Trial and error doesn't apply here because even if i fix it for en_US locale it will easily break for any other :)

Answer (score 0):

In that sort of case I would go for a TableLayout, in which you have one row, and a weight of 1 for EACH button. and the stretchColumn attribute put to column 1. Does this make any difference?

Comment: i tried it. this 0dip trick doesn't work with TableLayout. and if I go without it and do as you suggest, then next and previous buttons end up with a different width and i can't find a way to make them same size :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can match a size to some other besides by doing this in code. The easiest solution is probably adjusting the previous and next button widths in dp/sp units until they look good and have the select button be the only one with the layout_weight attribute.

Comment: This 0dip + layout_weight trick I used is a special one exactly for my case as i learned :) google for it, you'll find it. And yes, I guess I could do this in code, but i just searching for a way to do this in xml :)

Comment: I mean if you set your prev/next buttons to say 80dp width and your text size is defined in dp also the text should always fit inside the button regardless of screen size. Then you'll know your two buttons are the same size and select button will take up rest of the space as no other view has layout_weight set.

Actually, you might still want to use layout_weight for all buttons, just set the widths to a minimum that will allow "previous" to fit on one line.

Comment: the thing is that taking the possible future translations to other languages into account I can not rely on knowing the min width of text... i'd prefer to find some way to make android do all the magic :)