# Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have two `TextView` elements appear side by side (in a list item), one aligned to the left, one to the right. Something like:

```
|<TextView>               <TextView>|
```

(the `|` represent the screen's extremities)

However, the `TextView` on the left can have content that is too long to fit on the screen. In this case, I want to have it ellipsize but still show the entire right `TextView`. Something like:

```
|This is a lot of conte...<TextView>|
```

I have had numerous attempts at this, using both `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, and the only solution I have come up with is to use a `RelativeLayout` and put a `marginRight` on the left `TextView` big enough to clear the right `TextView`. As you can imagine, though, this is not optimal.

Are there any other solutions?

**Final, `LinearLayout` solution:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Old, `TableLayout` solution:**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'd like to up vote the answer too. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use TableLayout and put both TextView in table row, have a try. I haven't tried

Comment: Thanks, that ultimately worked. I've edited the question to include the solution I found.

Answer (score 21):

Just an idea, why don't you declare first in the xml layout the textview on the right and set its width as wrap content, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:gravity="right"`. Then declare the textview on the left, set its width as fill parent, `android:layout__toLeftOf`={the id of the textview on the right}  having `RelativeView` as the root view.

By declaring first the right textview, its required width will be computed first and occupy the view while the textview on the left will occupy the remaining space of the view.

I still have not tried this though it might give you some idea.

[Update]

I tried creating an xml resource layout... and it somehow works...

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="right"
    >
  </TextView>
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="too looooooooooong ofskgjo sdogj sdkogjdfgds dskjgdsko jgleft"
    >
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't work. The reason for that is that `RelativeLayout` allows its children to overlap, so ultimately the left `TextView` appears "under" the right `TextView`.

Comment: I added a sample xml layout. Hope this is what you are looking for. cheers!

Comment: About the left `TextView` appearing "under" the right `TextView`, it won't happen if you specify the layout explicitly that it should be on the left of the right `TextView`. The attribute `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/right"` will do the trick to achieve that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your solution. However, I ultimately found a `LinearLayout`-based solution which works better (for me). I posted it in the question body.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have to use a RelativeLayout so the LinearLayout solution would not work for me.

Answer (score 17):

The LinearLayout answer worked for me with this same problem. Posted as a separate answer because it wasn't clear what did and didn't work for the asker.

One difference. TableLayout was less ideal for me because I had two rows of data, and I wanted the bottom row to behave as this question describes, and the top row to span the area. That question's been answered in another SO question: [Colspan in TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710793/what-is-the-equivalent-of-colspan-in-an-android-tablelayout), but LinearLayout was simpler.

Though getting the widths right took me a bit. I included the android lint tweak of using `0dp` width on the scaling item for performance.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, because it is better to use LinearLayout rather than Table (or Relative) for such case from the performance perspective

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers to this and practically equivalent, duplicate questions on SO. The suggested approaches usually work, sort of. Putting it into a `LinearLayout`, wrap the whole in an extra `RelativeLayout`, use a `TableLayout`; all these seem to solve it for a simpler layout but if you need these two `TextView`s inside something more complicated, or the same layout will be reused, for instance, by a `RecyclerView`, things get broken very quickly.

The only solution I found that really works *all the time,* regardless of what bigger layout you put it into, is a custom layout. It's very simple to implement, and being as lean as it possibly gets, it will keep the layout reasonably flat, it's easy to maintain—so in the long run, I consider this the best solution to the problem.

```
public class TwoTextLayout extends ViewGroup {

  public TwoTextLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public TwoTextLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public TwoTextLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int count = getChildCount();
    if (count != 2)
      throw new IllegalStateException("TwoTextLayout needs exactly two children");

    int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
    int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();
    int childRight = this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getPaddingRight();
    int childBottom = this.getMeasuredHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom();
    int childWidth = childRight - childLeft;
    int childHeight = childBottom - childTop;

    View text1View = getChildAt(0);
    text1View.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    int text1Width = text1View.getMeasuredWidth();
    int text1Height = text1View.getMeasuredHeight();

    View text2View = getChildAt(1);
    text2View.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    int text2Width = text2View.getMeasuredWidth();
    int text2Height = text2View.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (text1Width + text2Width > childRight)
      text1Width = childRight - text2Width;

    text1View.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + text1Width, childTop + text1Height);
    text2View.layout(childLeft + text1Width, childTop, childLeft + text1Width + text2Width, childTop + text2Height);
  }
}
```

The implementation couldn't be simpler, it just measures the two texts (or any other child views, actually) and if their combined width exceeds the layout width, reduces the width of the first view.

And if you need modifications, eg. to align the second text to the baseline of the first, you can solve that easily, too:

```
text2View.layout(childLeft + text1Width, childTop + text1Height - text2Height, childLeft + text1Width + text2Width, childTop + text1Height);
```

Or any other solution, like shrinking the second view in relation to the first, aligning to the right, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a left margin on the right TextView? I'm using this approach for a

```
|<TextView>       <ImageButton>|
```

and it works.

Comment: It may work for you because your `ImageButton` always has the same width. Mine varies, so it didn't work for me.

Comment: Glad the TableLayout worked for you :) This was a similar question with self-adjustable buttons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530182/linearlayout-text-wrap-problem-when-having-two-buttons-of-same-size-plus-one-stre/3530322

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is a lot of content that should be cut" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Right text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I faced with the sililar issue, I did following:
I needed:

```
|<TextView, may be long> <TextViewFixedSize>      |
|<TextView, may be longer ...> <TextViewFixedSize>|
|<TextViewLong> <TextViewFixedSize>               |
```

You may use a solution like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutRecommendedServiceDescription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewRecommendedServiceTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewRecommendedServiceTitle">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRecommendedService1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewRecommendedServicePopular"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Long text"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRecommendedServicePopular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/services_popular"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewRecommendedService1"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```