# TextView and Ellipsize when squeezed by other TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I have a relativelayout, and in it two textviews. Textview 1 is aligned top and left with parent. Textview 2 is aligned to the right of textview 1, and to the right with parent. This creates a problem if the text in 1 is too long, meaning that 1 will push 2 out of the screen worst case.

How do I get these two to "sacrifice" from text nr 1 instead of 2? min width does not seem to work. My final goal is to ellipsize text 1, but seems to hinge on the textview to be sized correctly in the first place.

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/TextView02"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
          android:text="I am number 2"
          android:gravity="right"
          android:lines="1"
          android:minWidth="32sp">
</TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:id="@+id/TextView01"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:textSize="22sp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:lines="1"
          android:text="sd sd asd sad asd asd saasd a">
 </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, this is perfectly answered by this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a horizontal linearlayout using weight attribute. The following code will work for you. I set id s for your views as well so just directly copy paste this and it will work in your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Some Long and Random Text Some Long and Random Text"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"    
        android:text="I am number 2"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have a problem with this solution in my project, the first text is ellipsized as it should be, but leaves an empty space at the end, because it shortens whole words (and the last one is quite "long") so the second text is further away than it should be. Any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

get idea from my textview and just use your textview like this,hope it's work:

```
                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_songtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Song Title"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute `android:shrinkColumns="0"` of `TableLayout`.