# How do I set the android text view to cut any letters that don't fit in a layout

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have several TextViews in a row and I want the 1st TextView to take up all spare space but if the combined length of the TextViews is too long to fit on one line, I want the 1st TextView to be cut off.

As for the spare space I have set the 1st TextView's layout_width to match parent and layout_weight to 1 which works. I just can't get it to cut off any extra letters so it fits on one row.

What I want is something like the following with 'Text' and 'Long Text'

```
'Text   :data'
'Long T :data'
```

So 'Long Text' gets cut off to 'Long T' in order to fit.

What I get is

```
'Text   :data'
'Long Text :d'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the first (left) TextView a set size (set in relative terms, dp), or use maxWidth for it, and also use ellipsize.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

This is a good answer to your problem:
[TextView cuts off text when it is long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616631/textview-cuts-off-text-when-it-is-long-enough)

Also, seems similar to this question which may help: 
[Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58497299/2717821
 to cut left text if too long

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rightText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="|short destination|" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/leftText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="|next departure|" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```