# TextView cuts off text when it is long enough

Tags: android, android-widget

I have strange problem with TextView, it cuts off part of the text at the end. My layout looks like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPreviousQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_arrow_left"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </Button>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                style="@style/question_text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNextQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_arrow_right"
                android:clickable="true" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wvMultimediaQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and txtQuestion cuts off text when it is long enough. What is wrong, does anybody know ?

Comment: cuts off - when you display the text or when you parse it from the TextView?

Comment: @Damir can you post screenshot of text cut off. small confusion in question. I tested your layout, its displaying entire text given.

Answer (score 65):

Make use of these attributes

```
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
```

will append "..." at the end. But this will not solve problem in honeycomb tab

So for honeycomb tablet add the following atttibute also

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

On the other hand if you require marquee effect

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee" 
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true
```

Comment: Your code on the marquee effect only works for a single TextView in the layout.  If you try to have multiple items scrolling then it doesn't work.  How do you go about multiple TextView to have this effect?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there are some attributes you need to set, but first let us know what type of textview do you want exactly, single line or multi line?

There are some attributes you can take care of:

```
android:singleLine="true"  // or false
android:ellipsize="marquee"   // must check
android:lines="1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set below properties in layout file. It works fine for me

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect differing lengths of text for your view or you're going to change the `textSize` of different instances of your `TextView` then you should use `View.addOnLayoutChangeListener()`.

See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069734/1402087

Comment: I can't see any reference to changes at runtime. If the layout doesn't change after creating the listener doesn't do much. In fact, nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Set the layout_gravity on the TextView to fill

Comment: please be more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 
    android:minLines="2"

Comment: Why? What should that do?

Answer (score 0):

For me it I realised I was using the layout view of a different device to the one I was testing with. When I corrected this, I could see the textlayout was way too wide so I used this setting to reign it in:

```
android:layout_width="330dp"
```

Comment: Not a good example for wrapping up the text in small space. best practice must use wrap_content or match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the solutions provided here but none of these helps, finally got the solution using `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in textview.