# Have two TextViews side by side, the first stretched and limited, the second fixed

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to obtain a certain layout but all my attempts have failed short.

I have 2 textviews within a limited space. As long as there is space to show both, I want them to show one after the other:

```
| T1 T2222          |
| T111111 T2222     |
```

But when space runs short, I want only the first one to get ellipsized or otherwise cut, such as this:

```
| T1111111... T2222 |
```

It may help - or not - that both are only supposed to have 1 line.

It may help - or not - that the second's width can be fixed.

- I've tried the ideas at [Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize) but that case is different from mine because their T2 is meant to anchor at the right, whereas I'd like to have T2 just follow T1.
- I've tried specifying a minWidth for T2, but it doesn't seem to be honoured; plain width is, but I can't seem to control T1's behaviour.
- I've dabbled with weights, but found nothing that would solve the problem. But that may be my inexperience.
- I could specify a maxWidth for T1, and it it were honoured it might do what I wish, but the problem is that the whole width of the limited space is unspecified.

At this point I'm starting to think there is no way to do it - unless maybe programatically, which is a route I'd like to avoid.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would concatenating the two Strings and putting the result into a single `TextView` with `ellipsize="middle"` set work?

Or a layout, where the second textview is aligned to the right?

```
| T1          T2222 |
| T111111     T2222 |
| T1111111... T2222 |
```

**Update**
Taking advantage of the ability that the second text view's width can be fixed, the `RelativeLayout` below serves with the desired layout (by explicitly setting the second view's width to 60dp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="fill">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/secondText" 
        android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dynamicText" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/secondText"
        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"  />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code above generates the following layout:

```
| T1 T2222          |
| T111111 T2222     |
| T1111111... T2222 |
```

width an 5dp gap between the two `TextViews`.

Comment: 1. I hadn't thought of this, it's an interesting idea, though not quite what the designers had in mind. Thanks.

2. No, T2 must be next to T1.

Comment: Please take a look at the layout in my update, I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a million! :) I'd given up on this, but your example works perfectly. I'd vote the answer up, but I've just registered today... Just for the record: without gravity="fill", the RelativeLayout would only fill from the right; and if T2 isn't declared first, T2 will be ellipsed instead of T1.

Comment: I'm glad, you'made it, and even more happy for the challenge not being satisfied with my knowledge you made me learn. Thank you!