# textview in listview alongside another listview not getting ellipsized

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, ellipsis

I have this problem with text in textView not getting ellipsized at it end.
the textview is inside costume listView, when there is two list view side by side horizontally.
the textView Inside the left listview getting ellipsized but the textView in the right listview not getting ellipsized.[image]

the text circled in yellow (that's the left listview) is good but text circled in blue is not good (that's the right listview).
in each listview there's an imageView (the arrow), textView (the minute), another textView(the name with the problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution in this thread: [Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize)

add the attributes:

```
enter code here android:layout_weight="1" android:ellipsize="end" android:inputType="text"
```