# Place TextView at right of other one with multiline and elipsize

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I would like to do something like this...

Two TextViews, first multiline and on the end i need another textview

```
|t1 content t1 content t1 content     |
|t1 content t1 content... [t2 content]|

With shorter content

|t1 content t1 content t1 content     |
|t1 content               [t2 content]|
```

It is similar to the question anserwed here 
[Two TextViews side by side, only one to ellipsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize)
 ... but i need multiline solution

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

I have created this global function in which you have to pass textview object and no of lines after you want to ellipse end.

```
public void doEllipsize(final TextView tv, final int maxLine) {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                ViewTreeObserver obs = tv.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                if (maxLine <= 0) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";
                    tv.setText(text);
                } else if (tv.getLineCount() >= maxLine) {
                    int lineEndIndex = tv.getLayout().getLineEnd(maxLine - 1);
                    String text = tv.getText().subSequence(0, lineEndIndex - 3) + "...";
                    tv.setText(text);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: its not exactly problem with elipsize but with layout
ex. i am creating RelativeLayout... one textview is multiline and is parent aligned top/left. second textview is short and aligned bottom/right.

problem appears when first textvie have long text - it is elipsized right at second line becouse have attribute lines="2" but its under the second textvie...

i need to elipsize on a second line but shorter than the width of this second textview

maybe there is any xml (layout) solution for that case