# How can I display two horizontal textviews, one of which resizes depending on content?

Tags: android, xml, resize, textview, autoresize

I have a `ListView` that shows two `TextView`s, like so:

```
| Each row   |    has the |
| same width | as the row |
| before it  |  like this |
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
| Each left column | uses |
| as much space |   as it |
| needs |       like this |
```

Can this be done with just XML? I have tried [modifying this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785221/two-textviews-side-by-side-only-one-to-ellipsize), but it did not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap text views in `RelativeLayout`. Specify `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for both, and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for the left and right TextViews respectively. Set `android:gravity="left"` and `android:gravity="right"` respectively, as well

But in this case long text may overlap

another option is to use `layout_weight`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="some text"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, and the text on the left will overlap with the text on the right. Is there a way to make sure there is padding between them?

Comment: yes, for padding try `LinearLayout` solution (see edited) and add `androd:paddingRight="3dp"` to the left TextView, or `androd:paddingLeft="3dp"` to the right one, or both

Answer (score 0):

Something Similar to below should work

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="New Text"

            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```