# How to make multiple Views the same Width?

Tags: android, layout, view, size, width

As part of a larger UI, I have a `RelativeLayout` with three Views that I would like to have the same width. The three views are "stacked" on top of each other like this

1. `ImageView`
2. `TextView`
3. `ImageView`

I've tried various things such as setting the `View`s' `android:layout_width` to "wrap_content", setting `android:layout_width` to "0px" and `android:layout_weight` to "1" as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size/1177076#1177076), and placing the `View`s in a `LinearLayout` with no success.

How can I get these three views to be the same width?

Relevant portion of the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_above="@string/window_text"
            android:layout_below="@string/eighteen_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/line1"
            android:id="@string/line_1_id"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_above="@string/line_2_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@string/window_text"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_above="@string/top_row_id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/line1"
            android:id="@string/line_2_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're showing a RelativeLayout, not a LinearLayout?

Comment: I have several other `View`s under this `RelativeLayout` which use relative positioning.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is very simple, see below.  The "magic" is simple. Set the parent to wrap_content, and the child views to fill parent.  The smaller child views then always get set to the size of the largest child view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_row"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="more text" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="even more text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting android:layout_width="fill_parent" for the two image views, just like you have it for the TextView? If you want the three views to be the width of the widest, you can wrap all three in a LinearLayout that has android:layout_width="wrap_content".

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but they didn't work. The text overflows the images on both the right and the left sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image views to fill the parent width by setting android:scaleType="" in the ImageView but if the text doesn't fill the screen width and you want the image width to match the text width exactly, you'll have to do it programatically by getting the text views width and then setting the imageview's width to that.

Comment: I ran into kind of the opposite. I wanted my TextView's to not extend their width beyond the width of my ImageView. The TextViews, when set to wrap_content, were way wider than the ImageView. So I had to set their width in code. A layout_matchWidth item would be nice to have inside a RelativeLayout.