# Align Buttons horizontally with equal spacing in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i am trying to make a Linear Layout with 5 buttons horizontally placed with equal spacing, but all the buttons size (width) should be 40dp only.

i tried this :

```
<LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/button_layout"
                    android:background="#DCE1DC"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dip">

        <Button     android:id="@+id/button_A"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <Button     android:id="@+id/button_B"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <Button     android:id="@+id/button_C"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <Button     android:id="@+id/button_D"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <Button     android:id="@+id/button_E"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

its working but i need the buttons width to be smaller , how to acheive this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to make all elements inside LinearLayout same size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size)

Answer (score 3):

i guess this will resolve your query...

as you say you are using Linearlayout then you can do something like...

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="yourheight"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

//add as many buttons as you want 


<Button 
android:id="@+id/button_name"
android:weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if its a tablet then the width of the button will increase?

Comment: it works well for all phones...but with tablets i think it should...still not implemented on one...give it a try...and tell if it workd

Comment: and here you have mention the height of linear layout, i want the button width to be smaller

Comment: its just for keeping the height in bound...width will be adjusted automatically

Comment: and if i want the widht to be smaller then?

Comment: I am not sure, but you might have to reduce the width of the linearlayout and it will carry on...i have not done anything like that as my code demand was not that much...give it a try once...

Comment: and you can upvote or accept the answer if you find this useful...as it can also help others searching for similar solution

Comment: No such attribute as "android:weight" - did you mean "android:layout_weight"?

Comment: you mean android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 1):

For each button, change this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

To this:

```
android:layout_width="40dp"
```

Comment: yes it works but the width changing from device to device, i mean to say if its a tablet then the width if the button is increasing

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected. Android changes the width based on device screen density. This is because of "dp" = (Density Independent Pixel, aka "dip"). If you change to "px", then the size will stay the same number of pixels, but be smaller in size on the tablet. You can specify full width "match_parent" and then your two columns will even out to fill the screen evenly because of the "weight".