# how can I put 4 equal rectangle in one layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i want to make layout like picture but just use relative and linear layout.i want to mak 4 equal parts.I do not want to just put 4 button ot other objects.iwant just 4 equal space.

[image: 4 equal parts]

Comment: why just a negative vote?help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align Buttons horizontally with equal spacing in linearlayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749942/align-buttons-horizontally-with-equal-spacing-in-linearlayout)

Comment: see edit please @MohammedAtif

Comment: Make a generic LinearLayout, with a weight of 100, inside put other 2 linear that keep 50% of 100, inside these 2 new LinearLayout do the same thing but align them horizontally. Thank just assign a background color

Comment: @Mitro thanks a lot!you save my time,i am new to android ;)

Comment: @soft_94 I wrote the sample as answer, you can see, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution I state in the comment, as you can see is a nest of LinearLayouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="net.whatsgift.mitro.weightlayout.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:backgroundTint=""></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/red"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/black"
    />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/green"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Layout XML file just like your Image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F3FF33">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF333F">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D5DA87">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#1BE114">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if above code is working for you then please accept or upvote it.