# LinearLayout with two children of equal width

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having some issues getting two children of a `LinearLayout` to have the same width. This is what I am getting:

[image: screenshot]

And here is my layout xml for the grey box:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/medium_grey"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_profile_photo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="@string/blank"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/alert"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_rate_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate User"
            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/user_rate_up"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/user_rate_down"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I was assuming that setting the `layout_weight` of the children of the root `LinearLayout` along with a `weightSum` and width of `0dp` would produce the desired effect (image being the same size as the pink 'rate user' section) however this isn't the case.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

This is what I want it to look like

[image]

The photo and the pink linear layout should be equal widths.

Comment: i did't get your problem completly @boz.plz tell, what is your desired output??? i can solve your weight problem.

i think you should use weight insted of weightSum.

Comment: @Rumit I have added some more information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to make all elements inside LinearLayout same size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`android:weightSum="2"` should be on the parent of the two children ImageViews, not on the upper parent. Or else try to set weightsas `0.5` and see if it works.

Also, the widths of the two image views should be `android:layout_width="0dp"` when using weights like this.

Next, scale up your images to fill space. Details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: Ok that made a bit of a difference. The image and the child `LinearLayout` are now similar widths but they aren't 50% of the parent. Here is a screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/UuFHp.png

Comment: See edit. But your right image looks like it has not chance of being scaled as you wish unless you look at making it a 9-patch.

Comment: If I want to add third child that must be under the first one, but it is not?

Comment: This answer isn't wrong, but really only changing the widths of the child views to 0dp is necessary.

Answer (score 24):

Equally weighted children

To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".
Refer : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 2):

this is you want:

try this xml @boz:it will run in all size of layouts...!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33.33" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i take two linear layout with(50%,50%),and three child linear layout with(33.33%,33.33%,33.33%).among there three layouts, 2nd layout is your pinkone.

if still any query,plz ask.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the weight sum from your Parent View (`@+id/profile_action_rate_user`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,hope this will fit your requirement.
Try this xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_rate_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rate User"
            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/close"
                />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/profile_action_rate_down"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/close"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/close" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```